# Xamarin Forms multiply CollectionViews Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: xaml, xamarin, collectionview

I try to use a CollectionView in a other CollectionView like this. My problem is there wont display me the second CV like there dont have a source.
I guess the BindingContex can be the problem but i dont have a idea how i fix it.

```
      <CollectionView 
       SelectionMode="Single"
       ItemsSource="{Binding MainInfo}">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackLayout>

                    <Label Text="{Binding UserName}"/>

                    <!--Horizontal CV-->
                    <CollectionView 
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MainInfo}"
                        >
                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="10" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <StackLayout>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FullName}"/>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>

                </StackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: nesting CV like this is a bad idea and you should really avoid it

Comment: okey thanks what is the better way to reach the same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess the BindingContext can be the problem but i don't have a idea how i fix it.

In your case the ItemsSource and model should like the following

```
    public class MyDetails
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MyDetails> MainInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MainInfo { get; set; }

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));        
        }

        
    }
```

In addition , agree with @Jason . In your case if want to display an collection in cell, you could use [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) instead of putting a CollectionView in another . In this way you just need to set the Viewmodel and model like the above code .

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Bindable Layouts its what i search but i am still not able to use a horizontal Collection in da vertical Collection. I need the same like instagramm

Comment: Set the Orientation of the StackLayout

Comment: how i can accept it ? i am new at stackoverlow

Comment: Click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer

Comment: I completely overlooked this symbol